# apache ignite persist RDBMS

Tags: ignite, persist

code to reduce the Inventory count:

```
            ProductModel productModel = productCache.get(productId);
            productModel.setStoreCount(productModel.getStoreCount() - buyCount);
            productCache.replace(productId,productModel);
```

in my console it shows
WARN  o.a.i.c.s.jdbc.CacheJdbcPojoStore - Unexpected number of updated entries [table=t_product, entry=Entry [key=1, val=com.liwenlin.ignite.model.ProductModel@41a2aa2]expected=1, actual=2]

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue.
Would you please share reproducer?

Comment: I configured CacheJdbcPojoStore for ignite persistence, and load the data to ignite。the logic like this  - > Model model =  cache.get(Model_id) ,mode.setName('model1'), cache.replace(Model_id,model) .... then it will show this warning Unexpected number of updated entries ]expected=1, actual=2]

Comment: Please provide: full configuration for your model, RDBMS you are using (name and version), JDBC driver name and version. And also ignite version.